# How can I configure magit to use `diff-so-fancy`, not `magit-delta`?

Tags: magit, diff

How can I use `diff-so-fancy` in magit rather than `magit-delta`?

I'd like to *refine* diff buffer in Emacs with magit.
I found [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) and prefer it to [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) for several reasons.

I installed `diff-so-fancy` but *magit* didn't show diff formatted by `diff-so-fancy` but *Terminal* does by `git diff`.

Comment: I agree with @phils that is unlikely that magit could support it directly.  What is it exactly that you are wanting it to use?  The colors? (can certainly be fixed)  The file headers?  (could probably be fixed as well with some hacking).

Comment: Like this image, I mainly want to emphasize word level difference.
[diff-so-fancy image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3429760/32387617-44c873da-c082-11e7-829c-6160b853adcb.png)

I just found `magit-diff-refine-hunk` satisfies my needs but it seems buggy like this [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12025248/153365560-090eb401-e691-4fdf-abdc-8486013564ca.png).

Comment: I had turned on `magit-diff-refine-hunk` so long ago I forgot it wasn't the default.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that being an option -- how could Magit understand the output of some arbitrary visualiser?  It needs standard diffs to work with (whereas in your terminal you're getting read-only content, so it doesn't matter).

Comment: n.b. I don't know for certain, though; I'm sure someone will correct me if there's support for this.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.
[magit-delta](https://github.com/dandavison/magit-delta) does that.
And I just found `magit-diff-refine-hunk` basically satisfies my needs.

Comment: I didn't realize `magit-delta` was a package.  Perhaps you can just change `magit-delta-delta-executable` and `magit-delta-delta-args`.  If they both use ANSI escape sequence (which I assume they must), then perhaps `magit-delta` will do the rest.  You might also have to add `advice` to `magit-delta--make-delta-args` to prevent it from adding `--theme`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That made me clear how to custom magit-delta code!

Answer (score 0):

`delta` has a `diff-so-fancy` emulation mode via `--diff-so-fancy` or the `delta.diff-so-fancy` git config option.